# Dynamic meta tag binding using REST api SEO impact

Tags: web-applications, seo, meta-tags

In the web application, the meta tags are bound using the data coming from a REST api call . How will this impact the SEO , since when the pages are crawled , at that time async call wouldn't have been completed and thus the tags won't be available to the crawler. Is the there anything wrong in the concept I know about SEO , else is there a way that the metatags can be made available. All the html contents are statically served and dynamically bound in the client device, instead of binding the data in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the meta tags are coming on an AngularJS website, googlebot will still execute it and find the correct tags. If you're planning to host a webpage in which the meta tags are stored in the DB, then the meta tags will not be crawled by the googlebot and it might have an adverse impact on SEO